# How to Ignore automatically increased primary id on myIsam insert ignore?

Tags: php, mysql, primary-key, auto-increment, myisam

How to ignore automatically increased primary id on myIsam insert ignore?
How to solve this problem?
This is increased primary id rapidly. How to solve this

**MY TABLE STRUCTURE**

```
    | dates_tbl | CREATE TABLE `dates_tbl` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date_raw` int(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `date` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `day` tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `week` tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `month` tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `year` year(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000',
  `created_on` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `modified_on` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `date_raw_unique` (`date_raw`),
  KEY `date_raw` (`date_raw`),
  KEY `month_year` (`month`,`year`),
  KEY `year` (`year`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=21628 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

**INSERT QUERY**

```
    $q = "INSERT IGNORE INTO dates_tbl(date_raw,date,day,week,month,year,created_on) 
values $dynamic_value";
```

**RESULT**

```
mysql> select id from dates_tbl limit 10;
+-------+
| id    |
+-------+
| 19657 |
| 19681 |
| 19729 |
| 19777 |
| 19825 |
| 19873 |
| 19884 |
| 19913 |
| 19960 |
| 20007 |
+-------+
10 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: What is this table supposed to represent?

Answer (score 0):

- The table is InnoDB, why do you mention MyISAM?
- Get rid of `id`, it probably serves no purpose.  Instead, promote `date_raw` to be the `PRIMARY KEY`.
- Avoid redundant indexes -- a `PRIMARY KEY` is a `UNIQUE KEY` is a `KEY`.
- Usually it is better to keep year+month+day in a single `DATE` column, then pick it apart when needed.
- Do you actually use `created_on` and `modified_on`?  Or is that an artifact of some 3rd party software?
- It is more efficient to have an index on a `DATE`, then use something like

this:

```
WHERE ymd >= '2010-03-01'
  AND ymd  < '2010-03-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

With those changes, you have eliminated half the columns and most of the indexes.  And the `INSERT IGNORE` will stop giving you troubles.

If you keep the `AUTO_INCREMENT`, then let's see some more of the logic -- need to see why `IGNORE` is taking effect.  The solution may involve some of the other code in addition to the `INSERT`.

Of this is part of a star schema in Data Warehousing, then I will rant about how it is bad to normalize "continuous" values, such as `DATE`.  At that point, the whole table vanishes.  *And the code will run faster!*